# How to reduce your fingerprint in browser for privacy and for web scraping

Tags: cookies, browser, proxy, web-scraping, scrapy

You can disable cookies, change your ip 500 times but can’t anyone just track you through fingerprinting?

You could disable Java and Flash.  Though that would break the page and make you stand out anyway.

You could use Tor but I think if you use Tor you get blacklisted from some sites instantly.

What’s the workaround?  Using Chrome is a big nono.  Internet explorer maybe and firefox perhaps…

Are there any apps that deal with this?  Or just design a good web scraper, have an ip and cross your fingers.

I realize the average site is not going to implement all these features, but I am how one would workaround a site that was extremely vigilant.

Comment: Your question is too broad, but to answer it somewhat - scrapy doesn't execute javascript at all so there's no way for the website to generate fingerprint from anything other than http request and IP address.

Answer (score 5):

There are two types of browser fingerprinting:

**1. static fingerprinting** - can identify browsers (and probably operating systems) just based on details of their requests. That's the order and capitalization of http headers, browser specific headers etc.

One small aspect is described here: https://gwillem.gitlab.io/2017/05/02/http-header-order-is-important/

As this can be done without any javascript, I guess scrapy is identifyable this way.

How to get around this?

As mentioned in the above article you need to exactly emulate a particular browser's fingerprint by emulating its headers' order and capitalization (and it has to match the user agent, of course)

**2. dynamic fingerprinting** - uses Javascript to collect data on installed plugins, plugin versions etc ... As Granitosaurus wrote, that won't be triggered by scrapy. But sites that use fingerprinting for scraping protection will block the scraper if it doesn't get any data from its fingerprinting module.

As this type of fingerprinting yields much more dimensions it can be used to identify particular users with a high reliability (over 90%)

You can find a good example how this is done here: https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2

How to get around this?

1. use a lot of different real browsers for scraping (for example through selenium, no phantomjs, it can be detected)
2. randomize these browsers' settings and installed plugins (ideally using different versions)
3. when scraping rotate these browser instances instead of rotating IPs (each browser instance should keep its IP over its livetime)
4. If one of the instances is "burnt" replace it with a new instance that has a fresh IP and randomized browser fingerprint

... as you'll need many browsers this has to be done in an automated way, of course.

Resetting cookies sounds like a good idea at first, but if the fingerprinting system is worth its salt it won't need cookies to identify each of these machines reliably.

Comment: Thank you.  There are lots of Fingerprinting technologies.  Like if you go on here - https://browserleaks.com/canvas this id's you quite well.  Are there no commercial solutions that can be used to aid in web scraping to eliminate canvas identification and other forms of identifying you?  Ip changing is near useless without his consideration. So https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2 is able to be used with like Internet Explorer for instance.  I think it said it remove canvas though I would of thought that would raise red flags..

Comment: If I used Internet Explorer on my laptop, as it has a different GPU and CPU and so forth obviously the page displays different https://browserleaks.com/canvas.  IS there no way to just replicate that exactly on my PC.  So in theory you could just get laptop configurations and load up IE or w/e browser and it loads a pre-set list of settings rather than your default sort of thing.

Comment: https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2 seems like a cool option if possible though if it blocks canvas, couldn't you replicate the same settings of another Pc as its less suspicious rather than straight out blocking it.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I have researched the matter further.  The only viable solution would be to create a virtual machine that has different specs so it would be different.  Then if it got ip banned or whatever, you would simply switch to another virtual Machine.   This would counteract the following:
  http://valve.github.io/fingerprintjs, http://bluecava.com/opt-out, http://browserleaks.com/canvas, http://browserleaks.com/javascript, http://panopticlick.eff.org, http://samy.pl/evercookie, http://whoer.net/ext

Comment: Hmm or you could factory reset the virtual machine each time rather than fresh install though cookies could be an issue

Comment: I think you are mixing up fingerprinting with cookies and other cookie-like methods. Fingerprinting focuses on using existing data to identify a system. Cookies and similar methods create a piece of data to "tag" a system for later identification.

Comment: Also if each of the above systems has its own cookies there is no use in removing cookies, the browser will already be identifyable through their fingerprints. The key is here to have a sufficient number of such systems.

Comment: Thank you.  Though more advanced websites can actually determine your date and time, GPU characteristics and the sort so that technique would not work would it?  I believe mutliloginapp was created to bridge this gap and it is compatible with selenium which would work.  They do however have an api limit which is quite the glass ceiling.   I suppose my next question is, how would one change that of spoof such settings without multiloginapp.